# How can I fit the iframe height at 100%?

Tags: html, css, height

First of all, sorry for my english I'm still learning so I will try to explain myself as best as possible.

My question is, how can I fit the iframe height at 100%? I tried different solutions but anything works. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="header_PA">
    <div id="menu_PA"> 
   <div id="logo_PA"> 
       <img src="_images/1.png" title="Local PA" id="logo">
   </div>
   <div id="sections_PA">
           ...
       </div>

   <div id="user_box">
       ...
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sub_menu_PA"> </div>
</div>

<iframe id="iframe_PA" src="_local_pa/dashboard.php" ></iframe>         

<div class="smallFooter">
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header_PA{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 999;
}

#iframe_PA{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 73px;
}

.smallFooter {
    background: #121212;
}
```

I have skipped unnecessary parts of the HTML and CSS code.

The result of that, you can see it in this picture:

[Screen Capture](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/trkh.png/)

Apparently the width property works but the height no. Anybody knows how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a little bit of javascript to adjust the height of the iframe element.

this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR...nsitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>auto iframe height adjust</title>
<style>



</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//
function sizeFrame() {
var F = document.getElementById("myFrame");
if(F.contentDocument) {
F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+30; //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and Chrome
} else {



F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+30; //IE6, IE7 and Chrome

}

}

window.onload=sizeFrame; 

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>


<iframe width="100%" id="myFrame" src="thispage.htm" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
An iframe capable browser is
required to view this web site.
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Original source: http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?s=59fbfe0376deb43204ffff5aaf04736f&showtopic=26417#entry145317

Comment: Thanks! You gave me the idea, I modified a little bit the script because these instructions: `F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+30;` and `F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+30;` don't gave the heigh properly, at less in my case.

Instead of that script, I used this one: [link](http://webintenta.com/obtener-el-tamano-de-la-ventana-del-navegador-o-viewport-con-javascript.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to set the iframe width and height,

```
<iframe src="_local_pa/dashboard.php" width="100%" height="200"></iframe>
```